# Django Grappelli 3.0.7 radio_fields admin.HORIZONTAL not working

Tags: django, django-grappelli

Upgraded to Grappelli 3.0.7 with Django 4.0.10 and radio fields are stacking vertically even though specified as

```
radio_fields = {'show_weekends': admin.HORIZONTAL, 'group_by_dept': admin.HORIZONTAL}
```

If I comment out Grappelli in INSTALLED_APPS, they work properly so it's not a Django issue